# log likelihood function of linear regression with ordinal endogenous variable and sample selection

Tags: linear-regression, log-likelihood

I want to estimate a linear regression with an ordinal endogenous variable and endogenous sample selection.
Wooldridge (2010) describes a two-step procedure to do that. I would also like to estimate it using an ML approach but I find it difficult to derive the formula of the relevant log-likelihood function.

Can somebody help with the formula or suggest any reference where I can find the exact formula of the log-likelihood function?

Thank you in advance,
Nikos